# Tikz: Line caps when meeting circular nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I have a large number of tikz figures involving circular nodes (some of which are filled white), which are connected by edges (some of which are thick).

The problem I am having is that whichever line cap I use, the edge either doesn't properly meet the node (e.g. `line cap=butt`), or it bleeds into the white fill, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={line width=0.45pt, line cap=round},
    vtx/.style={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4.88125pt},
    whitevtx/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4.88125pt},
}
\tikzstyle{very thick}=[line width=1.65pt]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[vtx] (A1) at (0,0) {};
        \node[whitevtx] (B1) at (2,0) {};
        \draw[very thick] (A1) -- (B1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This draws the following simple figure:
[image: Two nodes conencted by an edge]

Here it is zoomed in:

[image: Zoom of edge meeting node]

Does anyone have an **elegant** solution to fix this? I've considered the following possibilities:

1. Place the edges on a background pgflayer. The problem with this is that the line cap defaults to `butt` so then needs to be re-specified (but maybe I did something wrong and there is a solution here).
2. Draw all nodes as coordinates first, draw the lines, and then draw the vertices over the coordinates. Ugh.

I have a very large number of these images, so the solution really does need to be elegant and simple, and ideally fixed simply by applying some new global style.

Finally, some other constraints: it's against the rules to change the specified line widths, and I would ideally also keep the `line cap=round` generic specifier for edges (though not necessary for edges between nodes, if these can be distinguished), as the styles set here will be applied to other types of figure too.

**Edit:** Thought not necessary in my particular case, a solution that could cope with **really** thick lines (e.g. `line width=4pt`) would get extra brownie points!

Comment: Maybe controlling the `outer sep=`?!

Comment: @Sigur I was struggling with this, because there are also sometimes thinner (0.45pt) edges, but `line cap=butt` applied to the `very thick` style, together with specifying `outer sep=0.1` (or smaller) on the `whitevtx` style might actually just do it! Thanks.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{very thick}=[line width=1.65pt]
` >>> we should not redefine `[very thick]` (already defined, see pgfmanual) although in this case it causes no problems. Also we should use `\tikzset` instead of outdated `tikzstyle`.

Comment: @BlackMild thanks for the critique of my code. Off-topic, but out of interest: why should we not redefine `very thick`?

Comment: @rbrignall because someone (maybe you ^^) can be confused with the name `very thick`; or when the code is shared etc. I recommend the name `my thick`.

Comment: Ah not too much danger of that in this case. This is proprietary code in which we've set the line widths via a global style file to match those of several thousand pre-existing figures drawn in the mid-1990s...

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
The background of your Ti*k*Z settings is unknown (to us), it is hard to judgement it. Anyway, from my experiences I don't see a good reason that all lines should have the same line cups (`line cap=butt`).  Especially because in many circumstance such settings apparently may cause problems. I would rather use this settings locally where is really needed and for shorter code eventually define new stile for this, for example

```
lb/.style = {line cap=round}
```

Your problem can be simple solved, for a some extend of connection lines thickness as has note @Sigur in his comment, by adding to circles style `outer sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    vtx/.style={circle, draw, fill=#1, 
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, % <---
                minimum width=5pt},
    vtx/.default = black,

        }
    

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[vtx]          (A1) at (0,0) {};
        \node[vtx=white]    (B1) at (2,0) {};
        \draw[very thick]   (A1) -- (B1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, for thicker connection lines you need to redesign your image to something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    vtx/.style={circle, draw, fill=#1,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, % <---
                minimum width=5pt},
    vtx/.default = black,
     lb/.style = {line cap=round}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B1) at (2,0);
        \draw[line width=4pt]   (A1) -- (B1);
        \node[vtx]       at (A1) {};
        \node[vtx=white] at (B1) {};
        \draw[very thick,lb]  (0,0.5) -- (2,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and elegant !

Comment: @BlackMild, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks! Though this has dropped the `line cap=round` global setting. Applying `line cap=butt` to `very thick` _might_ be ok.

Comment: @rbrignall, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had the "draw coordinates then draw lines then draw nodes" solution as an option in my question. Note that the constraint to preserve `line cap=round` was clearly stated in my original question - I've not said _why_, but I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: @rbrignall, well, why you than ask if you have a solution? What you like to have from your intention with ˙`line cup` options is not possible to achieve. There of course are some solution, but as you ask, they are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I asked for an **elegant** solution, because neither of my own two solutions meet those criteria. As my question begins, I have a large number of figures (so editing them all in a complicated way is very undesirable). At the root of my question is this: Surely TikZ should have a simple way to place nodes on top of the eges connecting them?